# Somehow my screensaver started kicking in just 10 seconds, how do I fix that?

Tags: 16.04, unity, suspend, hibernate, screensaver

I have my screensaver set to 10 min. and never go to hibernation. That works. Usually.

Somehow, today my screensaver started acting and after just 10 seconds the screensaver would kick in. Moving the mouse or using the keyboard constantly was enough to make the screensaver happy and not kick in.

I tried to change the timing to 30 min. then to Never timeout. It would still take just 10 seconds.

Any idea what could cause that to happen?

I'm (still) on Ubuntu 16.04. I have a desktop so it should not be a lid problem...

*P.S. Although I fixed the problem by going back to my console and restarting X11, it's not a great solution, hence the question here.*